# HTML Agility Pack - Get all links of a class

Tags: html-agility-pack

I want to get all the links inside a  with a certain class.

An example of the HTML is

```
<tr>
<td>
    <a class="dn-index-link" href="/dailynotes/symbol/659/-1/e-mini-sp500-june-2013">
        ES M3
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="/dailynotes/symbol/659/-1/e-mini-sp500-june-2013">
        E-mini S&amp;P500 June 2013
    </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

If I want to get all the links that have the class 
    class="dn-index-link"

what would be my XPath and HTML Agility code?

Thanks,
Will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A code like this in a Console Application will dump the content of the HREF attribute for all A nodes (at any level in the whole document) with a CLASS attribute equal to 'dn-index-link' ([Click here for a good XPATH tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("mytest.htm");

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='dn-index-link']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("node:" + node.GetAttributeValue("href", null));
}
```